# Change USER Model Primary key ID to another in Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a project where I have changed the User model primary key from "id" to "MemberX" using the following command in my User.php model file:

protected $primaryKey = 'MemberID'

But my Passport accessToken Table Still uses "id".I want "MemberX"

id

**user_id :::::Here i want MemberID not id**

client_id name
scopes
revoked
created_at
updated_at
expires_at

Comment: Why does it matter what the Passport table uses? (And why not use standard Laravel naming conventions?)

Comment: what passport table uses it refects in the token. The token contains "id" and i want to change the primary key id to another key

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your `User model`

```
{
   return $this->hasMany(Passport::clientModel(), 'user_id', 'MemberID');
}
```

Comment: public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Passport::clientModel(), 'user_id', 'c_pk_user_id');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if the driver on the laravel/config/auth.php has `eloquent` instead of `database`?

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent', //instead of database
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

`database` uses `DatabaseUserProvider` which the `find` method only looks on the `id` column.

`eloquent` uses `EloquentUserProvider` which the `find` method looks at the primary key if $primaryKey is defined before looking at `id`.