# Laravel Passport Overriding Primary key is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

1. I am using **user_sk** as primary key in users table
2. When authenticate with passport its not overriding primary key from model
3. Already palced User model have **protected $primaryKey = 'user_sk';**

> Its always shows error like this

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 32 limit 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is probably a relation that is breaking your code, based on the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451234/change-user-model-primary-key-id-to-another-in-laravel-passport), this can not be marked as duplicate since the question has not accepted the answer.

Add the following to your `User.php` model and see if it helps.

```
public function clients() {
    return $this->hasMany(Passport::clientModel(), 'user_id', 'user_sk');
}
```